# How to start kubernetes service on NodePort outside service-node-port-range default range?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, centos7

I've been trying to start kubernetes-dashboard (and eventualy other services) on a NodePort outside the default port range with little success, 
here is my setup:
Cloud provider: Azure (Not azure container service)
OS: CentOS 7

here is what I have tried:

## Update the host

```
$ yum update
```

## Install kubeadm

```
$ cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=http://yum.kubernetes.io/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
$ setenforce 0
$ yum install -y docker kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni
$ systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
$ systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
```

## Start the cluster with kubeadm

```
$ kubeadm init
```

## Allow runing containers on master node, because we have a single node cluster

```
$ kubectl taint nodes --all dedicated-
```

## Install a pod network

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube
```

## Our kubernetes-dashboard Deployment (@ ~/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or     implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Configuration to deploy release version of the Dashboard UI.
#
# Example usage: kubectl create -f <this_file>

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubernetes-dashboard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubernetes-dashboard
      # Comment the following annotation if Dashboard must not be deployed on master
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations: |
          [
            {
              "key": "dedicated",
              "operator": "Equal",
              "value": "master",
              "effect": "NoSchedule"
            }
          ]
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.5.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          protocol: TCP
        args:
          # Uncomment the following line to manually specify Kubernetes API server Host
          # If not specified, Dashboard will attempt to auto discover the API server and connect
          # to it. Uncomment only if the default does not work.
          # - --apiserver-host=http://my-address:port
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 9090
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 30
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8880
    targetPort: 9090
    nodePort: 8880
  selector:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

## Create our Deployment

```
$ kubectl create -f ~/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
deployment "kubernetes-dashboard" created
The Service "kubernetes-dashboard" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 8880: provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
```

I found out that to change the range of valid ports I could set service-node-port-range option on kube-apiserver to allow a different port range,
so I tried this:

```
$ kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
dummy-2088944543-lr2zb                  1/1       Running   0              31m
etcd-test2-highr                        1/1       Running   0              31m
kube-apiserver-test2-highr              1/1       Running   0              31m
kube-controller-manager-test2-highr     1/1       Running   2              31m
kube-discovery-1769846148-wmbhb         1/1       Running   0              31m
kube-dns-2924299975-8vwjm               4/4       Running   0              31m
kube-proxy-0ls9c                        1/1       Running   0              31m
kube-scheduler-test2-highr              1/1       Running   2              31m
kubernetes-dashboard-3203831700-qrvdn   1/1       Running   0              22s
weave-net-m9rxh                         2/2       Running   0              31m
```

Add "--service-node-port-range=8880-8880" to kube-apiserver-test2-highr

```
$ kubectl edit po kube-apiserver-test2-highr --namespace=kube-system
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kube-apiserver",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "component": "kube-apiserver",
      "tier": "control-plane"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "k8s",
        "hostPath": {
          "path": "/etc/kubernetes"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "certs",
        "hostPath": {
          "path": "/etc/ssl/certs"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "pki",
        "hostPath": {
          "path": "/etc/pki"
        }
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "kube-apiserver",
        "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.5.3",
        "command": [
          "kube-apiserver",
          "--insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1",
          "--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota",
          "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12",
          "--service-node-port-range=8880-8880",
          "--service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-key.pem",
          "--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.pem",
          "--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.pem",
          "--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-key.pem",
          "--token-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/tokens.csv",
          "--secure-port=6443",
          "--allow-privileged",
          "--advertise-address=100.112.226.5",
          "--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname",
          "--anonymous-auth=false",
          "--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379"
        ],
        "resources": {
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "250m"
          }
        },
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "k8s",
            "readOnly": true,
            "mountPath": "/etc/kubernetes/"
          },
          {
            "name": "certs",
            "mountPath": "/etc/ssl/certs"
          },
          {
            "name": "pki",
            "mountPath": "/etc/pki"
          }
        ],
        "livenessProbe": {
          "httpGet": {
            "path": "/healthz",
            "port": 8080,
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
          },
          "initialDelaySeconds": 15,
          "timeoutSeconds": 15,
          "failureThreshold": 8
        }
      }
    ],
    "hostNetwork": true
  },
  "status": {}

$ :wq
```

The following is the truncated response

```
# pods "kube-apiserver-test2-highr" was not valid:
# * spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `containers[*].image` or `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`
```

So I tried a different approach, I edited the deployment file for kube-apiserver with the same change described above
and ran the following:

```
$ kubectl apply -f /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.json --namespace=kube-system
```

And got this response:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

So now i'm stuck, how can I change the range of valid ports?

Answer (score 6):

You are specifying `--service-node-port-range=8880-8880` wrong. You set it to one port only, Set it to a range.

Second problem: You are setting the service to use 9090 and it's not in the range.

```
 ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9090
    nodePort: 9090
```

API Server should have a deployment too, Try to editing the port-range in the deployment itself and delete the api server pod so it gets recreated via new config.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried changing the range to `--service-node-port-range=8880-8881` and the result was the same.

The ports thing is just a bad copy-paste, I edited my post.

Comment: Please `kubectl delete -f`   and recreate using new config file.

Comment: I attempted to run `kubectl delete -f /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.json` as you suggested, but got this error `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Answer (score 1):

The Service node ports range is set to infrequently-used ports for a reason.  Why do you want to publish this on every node?  Do you really want  that?

An alternative is to expose it on a semi-random nodeport, then use a proxy pod on a known node or set of nodes to access it via hostport.

Comment: I understand the reasons behind the default port range and agree with them, my port choices are doe to limitations on the node i'm experimenting with.

I did not fully understand your alternative approach to this, it seemed like your suggesting to expose my cluster services via a proxy managed on the node outside of kubernetes or as a pod inside kubernetes that is mapped to the host port, I would expect a service would be the correct way to expose pods and the NodePort option to support the port forwarding with the host if LoadBalancer is not available.

Comment: If you have a single node, and you are experimenting, you can just use use a pod hostPort, without a service.  It's far simpler.  If you want to do this for real, we should talk about the exact situation so I can understand better.  My alt proposal is really demo-grade, not prod.  I know the NodePort limitations are awkward in some situations and I am very open to refinement, but I need to understand the use case.

Answer (score 0):

This issue:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

was caused by my port range excluding 8080, which kube-apiserver was serving on, so I could not send any updates to kubectl.

I fixed it by changing the port range to 8080-8881 and restarting the kubelet service like so:

```
$ service kubelet restart
```

Everything works as expected now.